# problema con bucle usando "while", termina inesperadamente

Tags: java, bucles

El trabajo a realizar es el siguiente:

Leer un numero e indicar si es positivo o negativo el proceso se repetirá hasta que se introduzca un numero 0 para salir del bucle.

Este es el código de lo que llevo realizado, pero falla después de que se digite un numero negativo por ejemplo -1 el bucle se cierra y en realidad el bucle debe salir cuando digite el 0.

```
package numero.positivo.o.negativo;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Usuario
 */
public class NumeroPositivoONegativo {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      //creo una variable entera  

   int numero;

        numero=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite un numero"));

while(numero>0 && numero!=0){

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"el numero "+numero+" Es positivo");
          numero=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite otro numero"));

        //aqui es donde estoy fallando. Despues de que se Digite un numero negativo por ejemplo -1 el bucle se cierra y enrealidad el bucle debe salir cuando digite el 0 //

 if(numero<0 && numero!=0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"el numero "+numero+" Es negativo");
            numero=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite otro numero"));

        }
     }
  }

}
```

Comment: Recuerda realizar tus preguntas en base a [ask], agregando un titulo e información necesaria, de esta forma te aseguro obtendrás excelentes respuestas, saludos!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

no lo he probado pero algo asi debería ser...

```
while(true){
    numero=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite un numero"));
    if(numero==0){
        break;
    }else if($numero>0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"el numero "+numero+" Es positivo");
    }else if($numero<0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"el numero "+numero+" Es negativo");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hwaw este es el mejor codigo. A comparación con la primera explicación. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda eres muy amable.

Answer (score 0):

En la lógica que estableces en tu programa defines que el bucle sucederá hasta que el valor de la variable `numero` sea menor a 0, esto incluye números negativos (-1) y que numero sea diferente de 0

```
while(numero>0 && numero!=0){
```

el valor -1 cumple ambas condiciones por lo tanto tu bucle termina.

deberías cambiar únicamente por :

```
while(numero!=0){
```

de esta forma el bucle terminará cuando numero sea igual a 0

---

Este sería el código:

```
public class NumeroPositivoONegativo {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      //creo una variable entera  

   int numero;

        numero=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite un numero"));

while(numero!=0){


    if(numero>0){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"el numero "+numero+" Es positivo");
    }else{
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"el numero "+numero+" Es negativo");
    }
      numero=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite otro numero"));

        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: @Dev.Joel gracias

Comment: Se supone había editado mi respuesta desde móvil pero al parecer no se realizó, ya agregue tus comentarios que añ parecer son importantes para tí, recuerda que posteriormente yo u otro miembro de la comunidad los puede marcar como "Ya no necesario". Porque razón no estas de acuerdo se eliminen aún y cuando se realizaron cambios en el contenido?

Comment: Muy buena tu explicación. Me sirvió mucho. La verdad no se como no pude hacer pensado en eso. Realmente me falta mucho por aprender. Gracias

Comment: Puede optimizar cambiando el `while` por un `do-while`

Answer (score 0):

EL programa termina cuando el numero ingresado sea `cero`, en otras palabras el programa sigue mientras el numero sea diferente de `cero`:

```
while(numero!=0){
    if(numero>0){
      // el numero es positivo
    }else{
     //el numero es negativo
     }
 }
```